# ERROR: Attempt to insert item 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 items in section 0 after the update

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, indexpath

My code:

```
    DataService.dataService.fetchDataFromServer { (channel) in
        self.channels.append(channel)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.channels.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
```

Fetch Data From Server Function:

```
 func fetchDataFromServer(callBack: @escaping (Channel) -> ()) {
        DataService.dataService.CHANNEL_REF.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let channel = Channel(key: snapshot.key, snapshot: snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
            callBack(channel)
        })
    }
```

Number of Items Section:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 0
}
```

The Full Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 items in section 0 after the update'
```

I am working with a collection view and have no clue why this error is showing up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show your `numberOfItemsInSection` method

Comment: just added it. Go an look!

Comment: You are returning 0.  You probably want to return `self.channels.count`

Comment: Make sure you have some data in `self.channels.count` and the count of it is not 0

Comment: have you set delegate and data source for collection view?

Comment: i have tried returning 1 by taking away the -1 and making it self.channels.count but it still does not work

Comment: how do I set the delegate and data source

Answer (score 5):

Your `numberOfItemsInSection` is returning 0, so when tell the collection view you are adding an item, it gets upset when this method says that there are still 0 items in the collection.

Your code even has a comment `// #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items`

You probably want something like:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.channels.count
}
```

Comment: No, this is the solution for the problem you listed based on the information you have provided. Are you still getting the same exception?

Comment: yes i am still getting the same error, so it didn't work, do u have another solution, sorry for phrasing my comment poorly

Comment: As I said, I cannot suggest anything else based on what you have shown, but it is quite possible that you haven't set up other things based on the code you had in `numberOfItemsInSection`

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and fixed putting [unowned self] in the closure and forcing UI updates to be done on main thread. Also, as the others have said, the numberOfItemsInSection  method should return the number of items in your array. Here is my final code:

```
DataManager.fetchDish() { [unowned self] dish in
        if let dish = dish {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dishes.append(dish)
                self.dishesCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: self.dishes.count - 1, section: 0)])
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For other users stumbling upon this question, these errors also arise when trying to update a TableView or CollectionView with no `dataSource` assigned. Make sure the TableView's `dataSource` is connected (when using a storyboard or nib) or assigned programmatically.

Comment: Lifesaver! Copied a collection view from one view controller to another and forgot to change the data source. Would have taken me forever to figure that out, thanks!

Comment: @rohan-vasishth pls mark as accepted answer if it fixes your issue so others can easily find it 

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you connected the datasource, that was something that tripped me up because its so basic and sometime you don't think about it.